# How can I get the specific definition of battery status in Android?

Tags: android, battery

As far as I know, there are seven values recorded in Android.

According to [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html) page, they are:

```
int BATTERY_HEALTH_COLD
int BATTERY_HEALTH_DEAD
int BATTERY_HEALTH_GOOD
int BATTERY_HEALTH_OVERHEAT
int BATTERY_HEALTH_OVER_VOLTAGE
int BATTERY_HEALTH_UNKNOWN
int BATTERY_HEALTH_UNSPECIFIED_FAILURE
```

However, that page does not tell me the specific condition of the battery.

For example, how hot the battery is - would that be called `BATTERY_HEALTH_OVERHEAT`?

In what situation would Android return `BATTERY_HEALTH_DEAD`?

Does any document write down the definition?

Comment: someone made a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10098979/3178454)

Comment: The likelihood is that those specific conditions would vary between device manufacturers.  Google might give them some guidelines, but they  ultimately choose what the specific conditions are.